# Jquery TagIt issue using ViewBag as datasource plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewbag, tag-it

I want to bind data to tag it with ViewBag and unfortunately it does not work.

So, here is my controller:

```
    public ActionResult ArticleEdit(Guid id)
    {
        ViewBag.Tags = db.Tags.Select(tag => tag.Name).ToList();

        Article article = db.Articles.Single(a => a.ArticleID == id);
        return View(article);
    }
```

And my view:

```
    <div class="tags">
        <label for="tags">
            Tags</label>
        <ul id="mytags">
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mytags").tagit({
        availableTags: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.Tags))
    });
});
```

It renders as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#mytags").tagit({
   availableTags: ["boool! ","asd ","asdasdasd "]
   });
});
```

If I use 
`availableTags: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby", "python", "c", "scala", "groovy", "haskell", "perl"]`

it work perfectly fine.

I tried regular jquery auto complete plugin with ViewBag and it works.
Here is code for it:

```
 <div class="ui-widget">
     <label for="tags">
         Tags:
     </label>
     <input id="tags" />
 </div>

 $(function() {
    var availableTags = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.Tags));
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
    });
});
```

Any ideas what can it be?

I am using MVC3 with Razor. And when I `availableTags` with `ViewBag`, input field just disappear.

Comment: Can you double check the rendered HTML, because it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/XT6Aj/. Have you checked in your browser JS console are there any errors?

Comment: I checked twice, it rendered fine. I have only `conditional compilation is turned off` in visual studio.

anyway it works now, thank for attention to my problem)

Comment: Hi @makambi. No need to mark the title as [fixed] - just tick your answer `:)`.

Comment: hi @halfer, `You can accept your own answer in 2 days`, it's better now to marks as resolved)

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten about that. No worries, just come back in a few days - my view is that, for consistency, titles are best without home-made tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I changed

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mytags").tagit({
        availableTags: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.Tags))
    });
});
```

to

```
    var myTags = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.Tags));

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mytags").tagit({
            availableTags: myTags
        });
    });
```

and it works now